# How can I generalize the data type in bind_param?

Tags: php, php-7

I'm writing a class method which will return data on the basis of parameters of the method.

```
      public function getRow($value, $name='id'){
        con();
        $statement = $GLOBALS['con']->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$this->tableName.' WHERE '.$name.' = ?')
            or die('Statement preparation failed.'.$GLOBALS['con']->error);
        $statement->bind_param('i', $id);
        $statement->execute();
        return $statement->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    }
```

Here like is the method is called like,

```
getRow(10)
```

So the query will be

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = 10
```

and when it is

```
getRow('StackOverflow', 'name');
```

So the query will be

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name = 'Stackoverflow';
```

But the problem is the data type of the variable is not defined, sometimes it is `int` while sometimes `string`.

**So how can I generalize the datatype in the `bind_param` function?**

Comment: You could map the data-type of the variable using functions like `is_int()` or `is_string()`

Comment: You should tag the driver as well. (if you saw my previous comment it won't work because you are using mysqli, not PDO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not specifying a type and just want to bind any dynamic value, use a "s" for string.

Since MySQL will still work with integers and floats wrapped in quotes, there's no point to doing a type check in PHP because it's going to end with the same result regardless.

Answer (score -1):

Although this function is for use with PDO, which I really recommend you use, it would be easily modified to meet your requirements.

```
//
// Return the proper PDO value for binding based on the data passed
//

 function PDO_bind($variable) {

    if(is_numeric($variable)) return PDO::PARAM_INT;
    if(is_bool($variable))    return PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
    if(is_null($variable))    return PDO::PARAM_NULL;

    return PDO::PARAM_STR;

}  // end of PDO_bind function
```

Comment: You don't want to use is_numeric for an integer binding, this would corrupt floats.  This also appears to be mysqli, not pdo.

Comment: Sorry, but I wanted the mysqli version I don't know PDO.